# GTK# layout rows of buttons

Tags: mono, gtk#

I'm having trouble getting the layout I want in a GTK Window and I don't have time to learn the ins and outs of the layout system for this simple application (which has to use Mono GTK# in spite of the fact that I'm not very familiar with it).

The layout is deceptively simple:

The bottom of the window should contain two rows of buttons, eight buttons per row.
The remainder (top) should be a TextView.

The buttons need to all be the same size and the bottom eight should align with the top eight. When the window is resized in the width, all buttons should adjust their widths so that all eight fit snugly across the width of the window. If the button text doesn't fit because the width has become too small it should just crop the text.

I'm using a VBox with three rows, the bottom two rows each having an HButtonBox, one for eight buttons, but I'm thinking that's not the way to achieve what I want. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Gtk.Table control that you use as follows:

- Have Three rows and eight columns
- Place your 16 buttons in rows 1 & 2
- Place the TextView in row 3 and span it from column 1 to 8.

You will have to set the Homogeneous property of the table to true to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks aquaherd. This was a throwaway app for a demonstration which had already taken place, I didn't see your answer in time so I had ugly buttons (which I did have to explain). Oh well, here's to hoping I never have to write another GTK# app =)